# How to rerender/refresh a child component from Parent component

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist

How can I re-render/refresh a child component from parent Component.

Parent :

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)

render() {
//I have a tab bar, when i tap on a tab the below line gets executed
this.childComponent = <ChildComponent onCategorySeeMorePress={this.categorySeeMoreClicked} />;
}
}
```

Child

```
export default class ChildComponent extends Component {
render() {
 <FlatList
          style={styles.flatlist}
          data={this.state.cardsMainModel.cards}
          renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
          horizontal={false}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractorInfoSection}
        />
}
```

Now from Parent on a particular condition, i want to refresh the child component.
Can someone plz say me how to refresh/rerender the child component from parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-render component with two vay:

1. Changing components state with this.setState() func,
2. Changing components which this given from parent

This are usual & suggested methods.

But if these not a solution for u:

you can use forceUpdate() method

I hope it was helpful for you

Comment: Ibrahim: I do not want re-render the parent, I want to re-render the child with some property from the parent

Comment: Try to send some value as prop to child and use `componentWillReceiveProps` method to setState based on the prop.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/flatlist#extradata